# How do I make sure that the fileds of the root struct get parsed first and then the fields of embedded struct gets parsed

Tags: go, struct

I have the struct as follows:-

```
type Inner struct {
    FooInner string `json:"fooInner"`
    BarInner string `json:"barInner,omitempty"`
}

type Root struct {
    Inner
    Foo string `json:"foo"`
    Bar string `json:"bar"`
}
```

I want the fields of "Root" struct to be parsed first and then the fields of the "Inner" struct. But here the fields of Inner struct is getting parsed first.

Comment: The JSON document dictates the order of the fields. So I assume you are asking about JSON marshaling (not *parsing*) and want the Root fields marshaled first before Inner?

Comment: Structs are not parsed. They're already in normalized form. So I'm not sure what you're asking.

Comment: Reflection of "Root" struct fields should happen first and then the other fields. Since "Root" is the parent struct and child in "Inner".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are asking about JSON marshaling (which is not parsing) and want fields marshaled in a certain order, a marshaler will typically marshal fields in their index order & recurse any embedded structs along the way. Struct field indices - as seen by the `reflect` package that `json.Marhsal` uses - are defined by their order of appearance in your code.

So put the fields you want first - and any embedded structs later:

```
type Root struct {
    Foo string `json:"foo"`
    Bar string `json:"bar"`
    Inner // <- move this last
}
```

Playground [Example](https://play.golang.org/p/IhgPfvBOIaz)

```
b, _ := json.Marshal(Root{})

{"foo":"","bar":"","fooInner":""}
```

Comment: Is there any other way by which I can make the embedded struct to get parsed at last rather than getting parsed first.

Comment: You'd have to write your own marshaller to prefer local fields first before recursing into embedded structs. But why would you need this? It's perfectly fine listing the fields in your code in the order you want them to be  marshaled.